# Multipart/form-data upload by PUT request, doesn't work on okhttp?

Tags: java, curl, okhttp

I don't know it is bug, or I am doing something wrong.

Here is my `okhttp` request:

```
private static final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_JPEG = MediaType.parse("image/jpeg");

protected void putImage(String path) throws IOException {
    RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBuilder()
        .type(MultipartBuilder.FORM)
        .addPart(
            Headers.of("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"image\""),
            RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_JPEG, new File(path)))
        .build();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("http://localhost:9090/")
        .put(requestBody)
        .build();
    Timber.d(request.urlString());
    okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
       @Override public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

       @Override public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
           Timber.d(response.body().string());
       }
    });
}
```

It gives error with at [the backend code](https://github.com/kamoljan/sushiobrol/blob/master/api/put.go#L56):

I thought it just backend code has a bug, however, It works on `curl`:

```
curl -v -XPUT -include --form asdfasdf=@Photo_20140806_000942.jpg http://localhost:9090/
```

My questions:

1. Is `putImage` correct and align with `okhttp`?
2. Is my `curl` command works very intelligently that make it works?
3. Or `okhttp` does extra things that my backend code should handle?

Comment: The backend code link doesn't work for me. Is that project public?

Comment: @JesseWilson sorry, I just relaunched the backend. Yes, it is public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to specify the filename header. Try setting the `Content-Disposition` like this:

```
Headers.of("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"Photo_20140806_000942.jpg\"")
```

Comment: you are right. it was because of `filename` ;(. Can you guys update [okhttp wiki](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes) it will save a lot of time for someone. Thank you again man!